# Can't install pyarrow on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, pyarrow, streamlit

I'm trying to install `streamlit` which requires the `pyarrow` module (Python lib for Apache arrow).
There's no error message, the installation just hangs indefinitely.

I did some research, and found out that probably `pyarrow` developers are not supporting Python 3.8 (not sure).

How can I use `streamlit` on macOS Big Sur 11.1?

Comment: According to its documentation at PyPI, https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/0.17.0/, `pyarrow` supports Python up to 3.8. But Python 3.9.1 is the first version of Python to support the Apple M1 processor: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-391/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

I updated `python3` to 3.9 (the default version was `3.8`). It should do the job, if not, you should also update macOS to 11.4 (or latest).

If you've not update Python on a Mac before, make sure you go through this [StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201612/keeping-python-3-up-to-date-on-a-mac) thread or do some research before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same situation with trying to use Python 3.12 instead of Python 3.11.
When install 3.11 problem has disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you perceive as "installation just hangs" is probably the installer compiling Arrow and all its dependencies. Which takes a lot of time.

If no wheel is provided for the platform you are targeting, `pip` will download the source code and try to compile everything from scratch.

Notice by the way that you probably haven't reached the point where it actually tries to install arrow (it might still be installing numpy or cython) because unless you have libarrow (The C++ libraries) already installed system-wide, then installing pyarrow from source should fail with a `"Could NOT find Arrow"` error.

Comment: Right but after upgrading Python to 3.9, all the compilation was quick, I'd say quicker than most of the packages. Note that I didn't install libarrow or anything C++ library, and